# Add include to CloudSearch in CLoudBoost

Tags: cloudboost

I'm trying to do the same as

```
query = new CB.CloudQuery('Class');
query.include('columnName');
```

But using CloudSearch, SearchQuery or SearchFilter. Is it possible? For example:

```
var cs = new CB.CloudSearch(Class);
cs.searchFilter = new CB.SearchFilter();
cs.searchQuery = new CB.SearchQuery();

cs.include('columnName');
// or
cs.searchQuery.include('columnName');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually, `cs.searchFilter.include('columnName');`